# How to find the first character of a String without using any API method

Tags: java, string

Recently I was being asked this question in an interview:

> Find the first character of a `String` without using any method from `String` class

Gave the following approaches, assuming `str` as a String:

1. `str.charAt(0)`
2. `str.toCharArray()[0]`
3. `str.substring(0,1)`

Can anyone suggest me the way it can be achieved?

Comment: You can't. It's a very silly question to be asked at an interview... (I'm assuming that you can't construct a `StringBuilder` passing in the string and take the first character of that, for example... all kinds of silly things suggest themselves, but nothing that's actually useful to know.)

Comment: All the interviewers asking this kind of questions  should see this comment from Jon.

Comment: You could use reflection. Or maybe `charAt` from `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I don't think it's very material whether or not the question is silly. I would suggest something along the lines of what @JonSkeet mentions - get an object that takes a `String` in its constructor and then use method calls on your newly-created object.

Comment: @Dan: It's material in terms of whether it's a useful question on SO. Personally I would have objected during the interview.

Comment: By the way, I have seen a similar question to this being asked in SO several weeks ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Matcher` API (and not `String`): we create a pattern that captures every character but only find the first one and print it (the [dotall mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) is enabled to handle the case where the first character is a line separator).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.)", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher("foobar");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // prints "f"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`s.charAt(0)` uses [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt%28int%29) API, not `String`, so formally it is correct answer.

Another option is to use a method accepting `CharSequence` as argument, e. g. one of Commons Lang StringUtils'.

Comment: [`subSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence-int-int-) is overriden in `String` class, same as [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection you could gain access to

```
private final char value[];
```

array from `String` class which stores all characters. So your code could look like:

```
String str = "abc";
Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
f.setAccessible(true);
char[] chars = (char[]) f.get(str);
System.out.println(chars[0]);
```

Output: `a`.

---

Also technically `StringBuilder` API is not the same as `String` so we could also use

```
String str = "abc";
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).charAt(0));
//                                       ^-comes from StringBuilder, not String
```

Comment: This uses a (static) method from the `String` class and thus does not meet the requirements of the question.

Comment: @DanForbes What method are you referring to?

Comment: `String.class.getDeclaredField`

Comment: @DanForbes `getDeclaredField()` doesn't belong to `String` but to `Class` class.

Comment: So what is `String.class` doing? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @DanForbes `String.class` returns instance of `Class` class which contains information *about* String type. You may want to read its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html.

Comment: I understand that `class` returns an instance of type `Class`, but what is `String.class`? Is it a static member variable?

Comment: @DanForbes It is not static member. `class` is a keyword in Java which has few meanings depending on context. In this case `.class` returns instance of Class containing metadata about String (just like `this` keyword can return current instance, or `this(args)` can invoke code of other constructor).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringReader` and read the first character:

```
char firstChar = (char) new StringReader(str).read();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another silly solution using a custom writer:

```
private class PseudoWriter extends Writer {

    private Character first;

    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (first == null) {
            first = cbuf[off];
        }
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {}
    public void close() throws IOException {}

    public Character getFirstChar() {
        return first;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
String s = "Lorem ipsum";

PseudoWriter pseudoWriter = new PseudoWriter();
pseudoWriter.write(s);
Character first = pseudoWriter.getFirstChar();
```